# Should I create separate SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a library web portal for various colleges, for now I am using a single database for all colleges. I am confused whether to use separate databases for each college or not. Because for now there are 7 colleges using that web portal, but in the future, if there 100 colleges using that web portal, all of them having millions of records in the database.

Comment: With **proper database design**, handling even tens or hundreds of millions of rows is **not a problem**. The question is more: are those colleges and their data **entirely** and forever separate, or is there any chance at some point one college might want to see / use another college's data, or share its data with others? If you have any requirement for sharing data amongst colleges - stick with **one** database. If you start separating them into separate databases, then you're entirely, utterly separated and sharing will become a big hurdle

Comment: No Sharing of data among the colleges

Comment: One major downside of having n separate databases is this: whenever you update something in your structure, you have to apply that change to all n different databases. This is not the case if you have a single database for all colleges.

Comment: Look online for "multi-tenancy" and how to resolve that for databases.

Comment: Yes , That is the problem if i have to update something in structure ,then i need to apply that change in all n database . That's why i am confused whether to go with single database or separate database

Comment: Can you risk one of the colleges calling you with "We've messed up, please restore our database from this morning"?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, stick to that single database for now. In future if that database contains millions of records, you don't need to worry.
You can migrate the data from that database to another one using the method Database Replication.

For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-and-replication-sql-server.

If you want to transfer between two servers like taking backups and restoring to the database on different server, you can use the method -Transaction log shipping.

For details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server